# In Python, As Iam looping through a file directory how do enter a text file at the root and replace strings that match re with xxxxx

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, os.walk

I want to loop through a directory with many files and append strings within a each text file. I can capture the string with re.findall method. I want to replace that string with xxxx within each text file..

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

start = os.getcwd()
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(start):
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        keepfile = files
        with open(keepfiles,'a') as newFile:
            content = newFile.read()
            text1 = re.findall('name',content)
            text2 = re.findall(‘_serial..\w+’,content)
            ReplaceWith1= content .replace(text1,'xxxxxx')
            ReplaceWith2= text2.replace(‘text2,’ttttt’)
```

Comment: What exactly does not work in this code?

Comment: You are not writing it back to file?

Comment: @Pratik Gandhi. That what Iam trying to figure out. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things missed in your code, but you can try this code.
Main changes  are:

1. open the file in `w+` mode to truncate its content.
2. changed the order of replaced content.
3. Writing eveerything back to `newFile`.

   ```
   import os
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import re

   start = os.getcwd()
   for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(start):
       if files.endswith('.txt'):
           keepfile = files
           with open(keepfiles,'w+') as newFile:
               content = newFile.read()
               text1 = re.findall('name',content)
               ReplacedWith1= content.replace(text1,'xxxxxx')
               text2 = re.findall(‘_serial..\w+’,ReplacedWith1)
               ReeplacedWith2= text2.replace(‘text2,’ttttt’)
               newFile.write(ReeplacedWith2)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with this, but i would test it in a directory you have duplicated to make sure it works to your specifications, which i think it does:

```
import os
from glob import glob
path = "/tmp/testchange"

f = glob(os.path.join(path,"*name*"))
n = []
for x in range(len(f)):
   n.append(f[x].replace('name', 'xxxxxx'))
for x in range(len(f)):
  os.rename(f[x], os.path.join(path, n[x]))
```

Comment: Glob has been known to miss files. So IAm trying to use os.walk. I am able to walk through the files but I know how to find the text. I just to replace the strings in each file.

Comment: Why do you think glob can miss files??

Comment: Are we trying to replace filename or the content of file? From OP's code it looks like we are trying to change the content